# Retrieve text from edittext to array string in android eclipse

Tags: android

I am making text to voice conversion app. I want to take text from user and change it to voice. when i made input text hard coded. my app works perfectly.

```
static final String[] texts = {"what's up dude"};
TextToSpeech tts;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btexttovoice);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    tts = new TextToSpeech(textvoice.this,new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener(){

        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(status!= TextToSpeech.ERROR)
            {
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            }
            }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(tts!= null)
    {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Random r = new Random();
    String random = texts[r.nextInt(3)];
    tts.speak(random, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

}
it works great but if i want to take input from user through Edit text
i make the following changes:

```
String[] texts ;
text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ttexttovoice);
texts = text.getText().toString();
```

Here i get error since texts is the array type. How can i get text from edit text to array type of string?
if i do this without array string

```
String texts ;
text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ttexttovoice);
texts = text.getText().toString();
```

i get no error but i didn't find the desired output. In fact no voice is received.

it seems a simple problem but i am stuck here. kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] texts = new String[3];
text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ttexttovoice);
texts[0] = text.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now my project is error free but i still didn't find the desire output means when i click on the voice conversion button. The project gets unexpectedly close.